# Pick a specific CUDA version to use inside Singularity 3.6 container

Tags: python, tensorflow, singularity-container

I am working on a POC of running tensorflow container via Singularity 3.6. I have a requirement that the user may need to pick an older version of CUDA which are available in a customized location rather than the system installed one.

I read the 3.6 document for GPGPU support, the -nv flag does all magic automatically, I could not see any step where I can specific which CUDA to use. I have multiple CUDA versions on the system and they are summoned by module load command normally.

Any idea is welcomed.

Cheers

Comment: To pick a specific CUDA Enabled GPU make sure your GPU is inside this list- https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Comment: Thanks. But I think you misunderstood my question. I want to choose various version of CUDA to use when running the container. Not the GPGPU itself...